# Relating records with a relationship ID

Tags: mysql, relationship

I am trying to think through this programming project and I would like some input.

I have two tables with records that can relate to other records in the same table or records in the other table.

Lets call table 1 book and table 2 bank. Both tables have the same layout.

```
+----+----------+--------+--------+-----------------+
| id | tranDate | refNum | amount | relationship_id |
+----+----------+--------+--------+-----------------+
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I can get an incremented relationship_id for every relationship and if I can do it only using MySQL code.

For example: To find records that can relate to other records in the same database I look for all records with a common refNum and see if the sum of their amount equals zero. If it does I want to relate them.

```
UPDATE book 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT refnum AS matchedref 
                  FROM   book 
                  WHERE  relationship_id IS NULL 
                  GROUP  BY refnum 
                  HAVING Sum(amount) = 0) AS t1 
              ON refnum = matchedref 
SET    relationship_id = ??? 
WHERE  matchedref IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: well, you can create a [sequence table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907077/sample-mysql-sequence-table-for-primary-key-next-val)

Comment: Does `relationship_id = MAX(relationhip_id) + 1` work?

Comment: There could be several matches that need their own relationship_id. I suppose I could do something like set currentID = max(relationShip_id) and then in the inner select do @currentID:=@currentID+1

Comment: Your question mentions two tables, but the example code only accesses one.  Is the second table relevant to this problem?  If so, how?

Comment: @eggyal, Yes the second table relates to the problem. I got interrupted and missed putting another part of the question in. I will do that soon.